# What is best practice for uploading a csv and populating a database with a React.js frontend and Django REST API?

Tags: reactjs, django, pandas, csv, django-rest-framework

I have a React.js frontend and a Django Rest API backend with a Postgres database. In my React frontend I want to allow a user to upload a CSV, which will be one column that is a list of products. That CSV will be passed on a POST route to the django rest backend. Then that list of products will be populated into the database with an auto-generated ID. So the CSV will go from:

| products |
| --- |
| floor tiles |

to(in Postgres db):

| id | products |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | floor tiles |

What is the best way to go about this? I haven't found a standard way to approach this. I'm assuming you would pass the CSV as form-data from the react frontend to the Django rest backend on a post route. Then you would parse/convert the CSV in Django, maybe with pandas or another package, and then post it to the database. Is this the correct approach? I'd appreciate any guidance or links to follow.

Comment: Based on your question, I understood that your csv file has to act like a model. I would create a model that holds your csv file and create a detail view with records id that will parse your csv file, and return a serialized response based on your needs. This way you will keep your db normalized by not recording every line on your files. You can update you model by changing the file in the model also you can add other fields to your model if you need other extensions any time. That is my opinion might not be the best one but looks like, you need a solution similar to this.

Comment: hi. your approach looks fine to me. but i would highly recommend to create database objects from your csv file in a celery task as there can be alot of products in csv and it will take time to create products and when you make your projects live on server there is a great possibility that your api will give 502 error if it takes alot of time in giving response